# Chicken defrosting for over a day?

Tags: food-safety

So I was defrosting some chicken breasts for a crock pot meal 2 days ago. I set them out Wed night and checked them thursday and they were basically still frozen solid.

So I let them defrost another day (since i've always heard frozen meat in crockpots is not a good idea)

They are thawed completely today, but it makes me wonder if it's safe? Since most defrosting is done in a day for meats...but I can't imagine the temp ever got too high up for too long? Our fridge stays pretty cold after all.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your last couple sentences imply the chicken was defrosting in the fridge the entire time?  If so, then the chicken should be fine.  (This is, of course, assuming that the chicken was handled properly *before* it was frozen, etc.)

Large cuts of meat sometimes take a few days to defrost in the fridge.  (Turkeys can sometimes take a week.)  The only time I'd ever be concerned about a multi-day thaw is if I froze raw meat right as it was about to expire.

In any case, I'd just be sure to use the chicken quickly now that it's thawed.

Comment: Yes, it can take a long time in the fridge. Withmy last fridge you couldn't defrost at all in the meat drawer. Even a small pack of chicken breasts would still be frozen solid after 3 days.

Comment: This is why I defrost in a bowl of water in the fridge. Speeds up the whole process quite a bit, but nothing will have time to go bad either.